# Easy creating fake object for tests from real object during debugging in java

Tags: java, junit

I was just wondering if this is possible. When I do JUnit tests many times I need to create quite complex fake objects for testing. Some of these objects are created as result of some process or more processes. When you put breakpoint in your code you have current state of the object. It would be really nice if it would be possible took this state and create instance from it or generate part of code which would do it for us.

Question is: is there any tool or any approach how simplify this? I mean basically take the current content of some object during debuging and transform it to instance (probably generating the code) to be able use this instance in JUnit test and do not need to create it manually.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to take a live system "snapshot" of an object and create a dummy object for testing from it? IMO this is a little risky since it may not be precisely relevant to what you're testing. If the objects you have to create are that complex then either (a) the unit you're testing isn't small enough, or (b) you just need a system for creating seed data.

Comment: 1. Be careful asking for tools. 2. When I debug in IntelliJ, it has an option to run arbitrary expressions in the context of the code at the breakpoint. If you imported a factory that creates the dummy objects, you could have it generate you one while you're at the breakpoint.

Comment: Could you just clone() the object?

Comment: @DaveNewton this is exactly what I want :) Of of course this fits only for some tests. But sometimes you just need some dummy object filled with some values and only test flow of the method.

Comment: @Carcigenicate do you know if there something simillar to it in Eclipse? Or atleast how it is called in Intellij? But if I understand it well you need to create factory for each object you want to generate. So there is no save of work anyway.

Comment: @user1097772 ¯\(°_o)/¯ You should use a seed data library or just create the objects. I've generally created methods that fill the known data, then modify only what's required for testing specific paths for each unit test. You might be able to serialize objects in the live system then deserialize them for the tests, but that can lead to problems later.

Comment: @user1097772 Tbh, I was guessing at what your intent was. I'm not sure if this will be able to help you, but it sounds like it might. And in IntelliJ, there's a button in the debug panel called "evaluate expression", which opens a dialog that lets you run code.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for hints I will try to search a bit. Writing tests is kind of alchemy sometimes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks i will try to investigate it.

Comment: Just painful when you have complex data to set up for it. There's no great way around that except to abstract out as much as you can so you only need to do the setup once then minor alterations for specific paths.